# flutter flame there is no package call flame_isolate: ^0.1.0

Tags: flame, isolate

there is no any package call "flame_isolate" but flame example  show "flame_isolate"  package in pubspec.yml file. how can I find that package

flutter version 3.3.8 stable,
flame version 1.4.0

Comment: flame_isolate is now published on pub.dev - https://pub.dev/packages/flame_isolate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flame_isolate` is not published yet, it will probably be published some time next week.

You can always go to https://pub.dev to check if a package is published.

EDIT: `flame_isolate` is now published on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/flame_isolate).

Comment: thank you man now i can enjoy falme